# Share uploaded file between servlets in session

Tags: jsp, servlets

Can I hold a uploaded file as a session variable and share in between different JSP/Servlets?
(i.e the file should be available in pages other than the uploading page.)
Or is it necessary to save the file in the server?
Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Just store it in a `byte[]` and save it as a session attribute.

```
byte[] fileContent = getItSomehow();
session.setAttribute("fileContent", fileContent);
// ...
```

You however need to realize that every `byte` of a `byte[]` eats effectively one byte of server's memory. So if you have 100 simultaneous user sessions with each only one 10MB large file, then already 1GB of server memory is eaten away. You'll risk `OutOfMemoryError`s when your server doesn't have sufficient memory and you've a lot of visitors. Think twice before you go in this direction.

Comment: I mean save to disk or keep in memory?

Comment: Store it in a temp folder on disk file system. Apache Commons FileUpload already does that by default for files larger than 100KB. On the other hand, you can use `File#createTempFile()` to have finer grained control.