# Share uploaded file among servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

Currently, I am having one jsp file, some java beans classes and two servlets. 
The first servlet is responsible to upload a file and print out the context of it.
The second servlet is responsible for fetching the java beans code, execute it and print the result on jsp. However this concludes to duplicate code in servlets. Duplicated code is actually that the file need to be re-uploaded in order to call beans:

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
Iterator<FileItem> iterator = upload.parseRequest(request).iterator();
File uploadedFile = null;
String dirPath = "C:\\fileuploads";

while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    FileItem item = iterator.next();

    if (!item.isFormField()) {

        String fileNameWithExt = item.getName();
        File filePath = new File(dirPath);

        if (!filePath.exists()) {
            filePath.mkdirs();
        }

        uploadedFile = new File(dirPath + "/" + fileNameWithExt);
        item.write(uploadedFile);
    } else {
        String otherFieldName = item.getFieldName();
        String otherFieldValue = item.getString();
    }
}

FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Next there is code which connects the servlet with the java beans. This works but my question is what is the best way to share this uploaded file? If I can store the file path in a variable and call it from the first servlet to second with no duplicated code.

Thanks in advance.

P.S I ve read this question as well,  [Share uploaded file between servlets in session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406599/share-uploaded-file-between-servlets-in-session) , but i didnt really manage to do it.

Answer (score 2):

> If I can store the file path in a variable and call it from the first servlet to second with no 
>   duplicated code.

So you would be just getting the file path and from second servlet you would be reading file again.

```
session.setAttribute("filePath",yourCalculatedFilePath);
```

and retrieve it from different servlet using

```
session.getAttribute("filePath");
```

You can just set the filePath in session attribute and you can access it across the session. but putting whole file into session isn't a good idea just imagine a user puts a file of size 1MB and there are 1000 users online at a time (just example) it would cost 1GB of server's memory.